# Android switch statement only sending 1 "key" value

Tags: android

im making an android currency converter app and i have 4 buttons on my MainActivity. When a certain button is clicked i need it to then send the string ive assigned it to my MainActivity2 where it is then displayed in a textview i have assigned. I can get it to send 1 (the very last case:statement) so i tried an if statement but same result....

**MainActivity**

```
public void firstCurrencyChoice(View view)
    {
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.usdButton:
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                a.putExtra("key","USD");
                startActivity(a);
                break;

            case R.id.eurButton:
                Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                b.putExtra("key", "EUR");
                startActivity(b);
                break;

            case R.id.jpyButton:
                Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                c.putExtra("key", "JPY");
                startActivity(c);
                break;

            case R.id.gbpButton:
                Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                d.putExtra("key","GBP");
                startActivity(d);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Main2Activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.optionOneButton);
        final Button all = (Button)findViewById(R.id.converAllButton);
        final TextView firstChoiceTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstChoiceTV);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class));
            }
        });

        all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main4Activity.class));
            }
        });

        Intent d = getIntent();
        String getA = d.getStringExtra("keyA");
        firstChoiceTV.setText(getA);

        Intent e = getIntent();
        String getB = e.getStringExtra("keyB");
        firstChoiceTV.setText(getB);

        Intent f = getIntent();
        String getC = f.getStringExtra("keyC");
        firstChoiceTV.setText(getC);

        Intent g = getIntent();
        String getD = g.getStringExtra("keyD");
        firstChoiceTV.setText(getD);

    }
}
```

---

Comment: what would you want `e.getStringExtra("keyB")` to return, exactly?

Comment: i noticed that i forgot to place the 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' because ive had to rewrite it numerous times but even when i do have them correctly assigned it only setting the text on the Main2Activity for the last case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting an extra with key `key`, but when you are trying to read you are reading extras with `keyA`, `keyB`;

Just get the value assigned to `key`

```
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: i  noticed i missed that and after changing it it still is only sending the last value...

Comment: In your `Main2Activity` you should have only one `key`.